# Retrieve a document-specific image from firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

please I would like to know how I can get an image from firestore for a specific user, for example how to link a user document to his profile picture located in cloud storage and display in the UI of the app.

Comment: When user uploads their profile picture add their profile picture link in their document in firestore.This way you can easily get image of any user using their documentId.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get the logic